# Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException Sitecore 9.2

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

I am getting below error in the logs, when I am overriding Sitecore Dependency Injection with Autofac DI. I am using Sitecore 9.2.

The main issue is with Create Actions on EXM & Forms.

Can anyone help regarding this?

```
15832 19:55:56 DEBUG Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating λ:System.Web.HttpContextBase. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: A delegate registered to create instances of 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' returned null.
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& decoratorTarget)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& decoratorTarget)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.DependencyInjection.SitecorePerRequestScopeModule.TryGetScope(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

Adding `BuildServiceProvider` Code below.

```
protected override IServiceProvider BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    var mapper = BuildMapper();
    var config = new Ioc.Config().Map(mapper);

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    serviceCollection.AddAutofac();

    builder.Populate(serviceCollection);

    var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    builder.Register(c => mapper).As<IMapper>().SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<MvcContext>().As<IMvcContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.RequestContext> ().As<Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.IRequestContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.WebForms.WebFormsContext > ().As<Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.WebForms.IWebFormsContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();            
    builder.RegisterType<GlassHtml>().As<IGlassHtml>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<SitecoreService>().As<ISitecoreService>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();


    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(SyncTask).Assembly).AssignableTo<SyncTask>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    //builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(executingAssembly).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<JobsService>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<JobAlertService>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<NavigationService>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<RecaptchaService>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<CandidateService>().As<ICandidateService>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<CandidateJobService>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<MyAccountService>().As<IMyAccountService>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<PasswordStorage>().As<IPasswordHasher>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<PageMetaMediator>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();

    builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var scope = c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>();
            var globalConfig = scope.Resolve<GlobalConfig>();
            return new CachedLocationService(globalConfig, new LocationService(globalConfig));
        })
        .As<ILocationService>()
        .SingleInstance();

    builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var scope = c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>();
            var globalConfig = scope.Resolve<GlobalConfig>();
            var currencySanatiser = scope.Resolve<ICurrencySanatiser>();
            return new CachedCurrencyService(globalConfig, currencySanatiser, new CurrencyService(globalConfig, currencySanatiser));
        })
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .SingleInstance();

    builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var scope = c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>();
            var globalConfig = scope.Resolve<GlobalConfig>();
            return new CachedSharePriceFeedService(globalConfig, new SharePriceFeedService());
        })
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .SingleInstance();

    builder.Register(c =>
    {
        var scope = c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>();
        var globalConfig = scope.Resolve<GlobalConfig>();
        if (globalConfig.GdprDataApi == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(globalConfig.GdprDataApi.ClientId) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(globalConfig.GdprDataApi.ClientSecret))
            return null;

        return new GdprDataService(globalConfig);
    })
    .AsSelf()
    .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<BreadcrumbService>().As<IBreadcrumbService>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<ContentSearchService>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<EventSearchService>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<JobResultsBuilder>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<JobApplicationsBuilder>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<JobFilterBuilder>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<CryptoService>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<CompressorService>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<ArticleSearchQueryBuilder>().As<IArticleSearchQueryBuilder>().InstancePerDependency();
    builder.RegisterType<JobSearchQueryBuilder>().As<IJobSearchQueryBuilder>().InstancePerDependency();
    builder.RegisterType<ArticleSearchDefaultsBuilder>().As<IArticleSearchDefaultsBuilder>().InstancePerDependency();
    builder.RegisterType<ArticleSearcher>().As<IArticleSearcher>().InstancePerDependency();

    builder.RegisterType<SavedJobBuilder>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<SavedSearchBuilder>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<BasicQueryBuilder>().As<IBasicQueryBuilder>().InstancePerDependency();
    builder.RegisterType<CloudDocumentService>().As<ICloudDocumentService>().InstancePerRequest();
    //builder.RegisterType<SharePriceFeedService>().As<ISharePriceFeedService>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<RedisCacheManager>().As<IRedisCacheManager>().InstancePerDependency();
    builder.RegisterType<GdprDataService>().As<IGdprDataService>().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var scope = c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>();
            var globalConfig = scope.Resolve<GlobalConfig>();

            return new GoogleJobsServiceHelper(globalConfig);
        })
        .AsSelf()
        .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<GoogleJobsService>().As<IExternalJobSearchIndexService>().InstancePerRequest();

    // Feed Builders
    builder.RegisterType<IndeedFeedWriter>().As<IFeedWriter>().Named<IFeedWriter>("indeed");
    builder.RegisterType<IndeedFeedBuilder>().As<IIndeedFeedBuilder>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<IndeedFeedModelSerializor>().As<IIndeedFeedModelSerializor>().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<ClickwiseFeedWriter>().As<IFeedWriter>().Named<IFeedWriter>("clickwise");
    builder.RegisterType<ClickwiseFeedBuilder>().As<IClickwiseFeedBuilder>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<ClickwiseFeedModelSerializor>().As<IClickwiseFeedModelSerializor>().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<ZipRecruiterFeedWriter>().As<IFeedWriter>().Named<IFeedWriter>("ziprecruiter");
    builder.RegisterType<ZipRecruiterFeedBuilder>().As<IZipRecruiterFeedBuilder>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<ZipRecruiterFeedModelSerializor>().As<IZipRecruiterFeedModelSerializor>().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<JobRapidoFeedWriter>().As<IFeedWriter>().Named<IFeedWriter>("jobrapido");
    builder.RegisterType<JobRapidoFeedBuilder>().As<IJobRapidoFeedBuilder>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<JobRapidoFeedModelSerializor>().As<IJobRapidoFeedModelSerializor>().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<TalentNexusFeedWriter>().As<IFeedWriter>().Named<IFeedWriter>("talentnexus");
    builder.RegisterType<TalentNexusFeedBuilder>().As<ITalentNexusFeedBuilder>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<TalentNexusFeedModelSerializor>().As<ITalentNexusFeedModelSerializor>().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<ForcesNetRecruiterFeedWriter>().As<IFeedWriter>().Named<IFeedWriter>("forcesnet");
    builder.RegisterType<ForcesNetRecruiterFeedBuilder>().As<IForcesNetRecruiterFeedBuilder>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<ForcesNetRecruiterFeedModelSerializor>().As<IForcesNetRecruiterFeedModelSerializor>().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.Register<FeedBuilderFactory>((context, parameters) =>
        {
            var scope = context.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>();
            return type =>
            {
                var builderType = type.ToLower().Trim();
                return scope.ResolveOptionalNamed<IFeedWriter>(builderType);
            };
        }).AsSelf().InstancePerDependency();
    builder.Register<SyncTask.SyncTaskFactory>(c =>
        {
            var scope = c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>();
            return (t => scope.Resolve(t) as SyncTask);
        }).AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.Register(c => config).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<JobSearchFilterCoodinateLookup>().As<IJobSearchFilterCoordinateLookup>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<SalaryNormaliser>().As<ISalaryNormaliser>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<JobsSearchResultVmBuilder>().As<IJobsSearchResultVmBuilder>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<TimeRemainingVmBuilder>().As<ITimeRemainingVmBuilder>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<SalaryDescriptionBuilder>().As<ISalaryDescriptionBuilder>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<CurrencySanatiser>().As<ICurrencySanatiser>().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<JobSearcher>().As<IJobSearcher>().InstancePerRequest();

    //builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)).As<HttpContextBase>().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterModule<MediatRModule>();
    //builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());

    builder.RegisterControllers(executingAssembly);
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(executingAssembly);

    builder.RegisterModelBinders(typeof(JobFilterModelBinder).Assembly);
    builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();
    builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

    //builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(executingAssembly);

    var container = builder.Build();

    var mvcResolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
    var webApiResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);                                 


    // Register the resolver as the ASP.net WebApi2 resolver.
    //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new ConditionalDependencyResolver(webApiResolver, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver);

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = webApiResolver;

    // Register the resolver as the ASP.net MVC resolver.

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(mvcResolver);

    AutofacDependencyResolver.SetAutofacDependencyResolverAccessor(() => mvcResolver);

    // Register the resolver with Sitecore controller factory.
    //ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new AutofacControllerFactory(mvcResolver, ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory()));

    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Service", @"service/{action}", new { controller = "Service" });
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Indeed", @"feed/{builderType}/{jobRepositoryId}", new { controller = "Feed", action = "Build", jobRepositoryId = UrlParameter.Optional });
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("SitecoreShellDefault", @"sitecore/shell/mvc/{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "CustomEditor" });

    AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true;

    //Translate.ResetCache(true);

    // Custom model binders
    //HttpContext.Current.Items["77D90B5A-236C-4116-8C4E-E4517753E74C"] = new VersionCountDisabler();

    RegisterSocialDependencies();          

    return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
}
```

Comment: I guess the issue is because Sitecore EXM or forms are based on Sitecore MVC controllers and AutoFac is not able to resolve them, Please share the code on how you are registering  Autofac

Comment: Hi Abhay, I am extending the Default ServiceProvider and overriding it with Autofac. Then I patched the Service Provider using configuration patch file. Can you let me know how you can register the Sitecore MVC Controllers in Autofac?

Comment: I have updated the BuildServiceProvider Method Code as well.

Comment: Yes , your implementation looks correct , but you may also need a chainedmvcresolver  https://sitecorecorner.com/2016/01/20/sitecore-mvc-autofac-dependency-resolution/

Comment: https://medium.com/@structuredcode/replacing-the-default-di-container-in-sitecore-8-2-4e65d4956c99 
Which Sitecoreversion are you using ?

Comment: I am using Sitecore 9.2

Comment: We had this issue too, Sitecore Support said that Autofac isn't fully supported. Considering its slower than Microsoft Dependency Injection, and is not tested by Sitecore, I'd advise not using it.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with structure map DI, Forms load properly after removing DI. I want to have both DI and Sitecore forms.Can someone please suggest a solution?